# Number of roots of irreducible polynomials in extension fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, roots, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Let $k$ be a field and $p$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ in $k[x]$.  Let $E$ be a field extension of $k$.  Can anything be said about the number of roots of $p$ that are present in $E$?

I suspect that the number must divide $n$, but I don't see how to construct a proof.

Comment: What exactly do we know about $k$ as a field? What do we know about $E$? The question seems too broad to have an adequate answer as is.

Comment: Are you familiar with the construction of a splitting field? Do you see that if $\deg p(x)=n$, and the splitting field $L=k(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ happens to have the maximal degree $n!$, it follows that the intermediate field
$$E_\ell=k(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_{\ell})$$
has exactly $\ell$ zeros of $p$. Here $0\le\ell< n-1$ can be any integer in the range. So only $n-1$ is impossible. That is obvious because the sum of all the roots is an element of $k$, whence the last zero can be written in terms of the rest and an element of $k$.

Comment: (cont'd) The condition $[L:k]=n!$ is equivalent to the Galois group being isomorphic to $S_n$. Over $\Bbb{Q}$ that occurs as the Galois group for all $n$.

Comment: (cont'd) On the other hand, your conjecture is true for example when $k$ is finite, when the only alternatives are $1$ and $n$.

Comment: @Angel Nothing.  I'd consider a counter-example to my hypothesis an adequate answer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks!  Google (https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisaspermgp.pdf) suggests as an example that the Galois group is isomorphic to $S_n$ when $k = \mathbb{Q}$ and $p(x)$ has prime degree and all but two roots in $\mathbb{R}$.  If you turn your comments into an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.